# How can I create this alternating layout?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is the HTML I need to use:

```
<div class="images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

I tried `:nth-child() even/odd/xn+x` etc. - no luck, I can't figure out what calculation to do. Adding dynamic CSS classes via PHP is fine if needed.

I'm trying to achieve this layout:

[image]

Comment: This question is demonstrably not too broad as evidenced by answers given less than 30 minutes after the question was asked (with a single sentence followed by code, no less).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this. Your pattern is repeating each 4 elements so you need to consider `nth-child(4n + x)`:

```css
.images {
  display:flex;
  min-height:100vh;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content:flex-start;
}
.image {
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.image:nth-child(4n+1),
.image:nth-child(4n+4) {
   width:40%;
   background:red;
}

.image:nth-child(4n+2),
.image:nth-child(4n+3) {
   width:60%;
   background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact simplify the CSS from the accepted answer:

```css
.images {
  display:flex;
  min-height:100vh;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-content:flex-start;
}
.image {
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:60%;
  background:blue;
}

.image:nth-child(4n),
.image:nth-child(4n+1) {
   width:40%;
   background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.images .odd {
    float:left;
}
.images .even {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="image odd"></div>
  <div class="image even"></div>
  <div class="image odd"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it's not that simple, I already tried "even" "odd" and it is not enough