# Css block layout - even/odd?

Tags: css, layout

I'm working on the front-end of Wordpress website. The layout of the projects is: 2 projects per row. The first project 2/3 width, second one is 1/3 width, the third one also 1/3, fourth is 2/3. There can be unlimited number of projects, but the last project is always 100% width.

[image: Screenshot of the wanted layout below:]

Can this be done by only using CSS?
I thought of :nth-child(odd) and :nth-child(even). But sometimes the odd is 2/3 and sometimes the other one...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50541486/how-can-i-create-this-alternating-layout/50541673#50541673

Comment: @TemaniAfif I wouldn't mark this as duplicate because the last element has to have 100% width.

Comment: @dennis-perremans If _the last project is always 100% width_ and there are even number of tiles, then the last two will be 100% wide?

Comment: @shirfy I didn't mark as duplicate ;) I simply commented as a possible duplicate so he get some idea ... you may notice that I have the Gold CSS, so if I was sure about it will get closed immediately :)

Comment: @shirfy if there are an even number of tiles, there wouldn't be a last one width 100%. Only if there is an uneven number of tiles, the last one should be 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following structure to create the layout you want.

```css
    .container div {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      display: inline-block;
      border:solid 1px blue;
      margin:5px;
    }
    .container section {
      width:100%;
      display:flex;
    }
    .container section:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(even) {
       width:75%;
    }
    .container section:nth-child(odd) > div:nth-child(odd) {
       width:24%;
    }
    .container section:nth-child(even) > div:nth-child(odd) {
      width:75%;
    }
    .container section:nth-child(even) > div:nth-child(even) {
        width:24%;
    }
    .container section:last-child > div:nth-child(1) { 
      border: solid 1px red !important;
      width:100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <section> 
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    </section>
    <section>
    <div> 3 </div> 
    <div> 4 </div> 
    </section>

    <section> <div> 5 </div> </section>
</div>
```

Comment: @SuperDJ Not possible to put sections around every 2 elements.

Comment: @DennisPerremans this is not my answer I only edited the answer. They don't have to be sections. They can be any element with a specific class aswell. SO isn't always going to give you a copy paste answers. Some will only give you pointers to the right answer

Comment: @DennisPerremans I have added another answer, see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go without sections/ outer elements:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 24%;
}

.container div:nth-child(2n),
.container div:nth-child(3n) {
  width: 73%;
}

.container div:nth-child(2n+3) {
  width: 73%;
}

.container div:nth-child(4n),
.container div:nth-child(4n+1) {
  width: 24%;
}

.container div:last-child {
  border: solid 1px red !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
  <div> 6 </div>
  <div> 7 </div>
  <div> 8 </div>
  <div> 1 </div>
  <div> 2 </div>
  <div> 3 </div>
  <div> 4 </div>
  <div> 5 </div>
  <div> 6 </div>
  <div> 7 </div>
  <div> 8 </div>
  <div> Last </div>
</div>
```